# OctoberCMS: How to remove the delete button of update page

Tags: octobercms, october-form-controller

I am using the `FormController` behavior for a controller. There is a `delete` button (trash icon) in the `Update` page which I need to hide for logged in users who are not superuser. I can remove the `delete` button by simply removing its html from the `update.htm` file:

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="oc-icon-trash-o btn-icon danger pull-right"
    data-request="onDelete"
    data-load-indicator="<?= e(trans('backend::lang.form.deleting')) ?>"
    data-request-confirm="<?= e(trans('backend::lang.form.confirm_delete')) ?>">
</button>
```

But this will remove the delete button for all users. I only want to remove this button if the logged in backend user is not admin. How can I do this dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the user is superuser because your view has access to the user object

```php
<?php if($this->user->is_superuser): ?>
    <button
     type="button"
     class="oc-icon-trash-o btn-icon danger pull-right"
     data-request="onDelete"
     data-load-indicator="<?= e(trans('backend::lang.form.deleting')) ?>"
     data-request-confirm="<?= e(trans('backend::lang.form.confirm_delete')) ?>">
    </button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Check this out as well https://octobercms.com/forum/post/hide-backend-columnsfields-with-permissions